# Implementing a SOA in Django using celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I want to implement a web app with a SOA design. I am thinking of using celery in conjunction with Django to do this. But I have some questions:

1. Is this the correct way to go in order to implement a SOA design for Django
2. Assuming that this is the way to go, how would I accomplish authentication within the Django framework. Specifically, I would like authentication to be decoupled with a producer and consumer pattern. That way, a REST api (or anything for that matter) can be used to produce the authentication credentials, and a consumer (within the Django framework) can be used to read and act upon the credentials.

Again, should I do the above with Celery in Django?

Comment: It seems that the Ruby community (Rails specifically) is more adept to building and using SOA. I have just acquired a book called _Service-Oriented design with Ruby and Rails_ that will shed light on how one implements a SOA paradigm in Rails. I like Python a bit more than Rails, so I would like to accomplish the same thing using Django. So I am going to see if the concepts mentioned in this books translates to Django. I will report back here. But if push comes to shove, I will use Rails (which I think is also a pretty nifty language).

Answer (score 9):

A message queue (such as rabbitmq brokered by celery) is a perfectly fine way to handle communication between SOA components.  Additionally, if you need real-time communication without sharing databases between services, REST is basically made for this.  There are several options for implementing REST services on top of Django, with Tastypie and Django-Rest-Framework being popular choices.

As for passing authentication between components, Django has several options for this.  Contrary to popular opinion, the Django authentication framework is extremely flexible, supporting authorization/authentication against anything you can write a backend for.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend for documentation on this.

There are numerous examples of this already:

- Consume ZenDesk's SSO: http://www.jongales.com/blog/2009/05/12/zendesk-remote-authentication-with-django/
- Consume SSO from numerous social networks:  [django-social-auth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-social-auth/) or [django-allauth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-allauth/)
- Consume LDAP:    http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/

As for publishing auth, there are fewer options, but these include:

- SAML: https://opensourcemissions.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/django-saml-2-0-identity-provider/
- Oauth: http://djangopackages.com/search/?q=oauth

I strongly suggest using a provider package already built and tested over rolling your own.  Implementing SSO is deceptively tricky.

Answer (score 4):

Django is not really built for SOA. In the case of authentication, Django has a well-defined authentication framework that will easily allow you to reuse it across Web, API, etc.

Generally speaking, if you want the flexibility to define your own architecture, Django probably isn't for you. You might want to consider something more minimalist like [web.py](http://webpy.org/).

Comment: I know Django has its own authentication module built in, but if one can use celery within DJango, why can't one separate these processes by using a SOA approach?

Comment: You certainly can, but you're not really making much use of the framework if you intend to approach problems this way. If that's the case, a lighter weight framework seems more appropriate.